# How transform object that contain arrays in keys to array of string with certain field?

Tags: javascript

I just have object, that contains arrays in keys, and I need get array of string with
name property. I cope to do it with flat, but probably there is better solution

```
const testObj = {
 first: [ { name: 'Den' }, { name: 'Ben' } ],
 second: [ { name: 'Ken} ]
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
['Den', 'Ben', 'Ken' ]
```

**My solution:**

```
const res = Object.keys(testObj).map(key=>{
  return testObj[key].map(el=>el.name)
}).flat(1)
```

Comment: what is the problem with your solution?

Comment: I don't want to use flat, flatMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` instead of calling `map` and `flat` separately. Also you can replace `Object.keys` with `Object.values`

```js
const testObj = {
    first: [ { name: 'Den' }, { name: 'Ben' } ],
    second: [ { name: 'Ken'} ]
}

const res = Object.values(testObj).flatMap(val => val.map(el => el.name))

console.log(res)
```

If you can't use `flatMap`, you can flatten the array using `Array.prototype.concat`:

```js
const testObj = {
    first: [ { name: 'Den' }, { name: 'Ben' } ],
    second: [ { name: 'Ken'} ]
}

const res = [].concat.apply([], Object.values(testObj).map(val => val.map(el => el.name)));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks efficient...

```
const testObj = {
    first: [ { name: 'Den' }, { name: 'Ben' } ],
    second: [ { name: 'Ken'} ]
}
let sol = [];
Object.values(testObj).forEach( list => list.forEach( el => sol.push(el.name)))
console.log(sol);
```